# Question about $\forall$ and $\exists$

Tags: logic, asymptotics, quantifiers

The problem is:

> Prove that $(\forall g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+)(\exists f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+)(\forall c, B \in \mathbb{R}^+)(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})(n \geq B \wedge f(n) > cg(n))$

My question  is that when you assume $g(n)$ can you let $f(n) = cg(n) + 1, c \in R^+$ even though the $\forall c \in R^+$ comes after the $\exists f$. Can you assume that the two $c$'s will be the same?

Comment: No.  Given a $g$, you need to find a single $f$ that works for all $c$ and $B$, so, in particular, its definition has to be independent of $c$ and $B$ (but may depend on $g$).

Comment: Then can you suggest how to select $f$?

Comment: The question is worded somewhat strangely, since you can actually prove a stronger statement, that also happens to be a more natural statement to consider in the context of asymptotics, and is probably easier to think about.  Namely, try proving:

Comment: $\forall g, \exists f, \forall c, \exists B, \forall n (n > B \rightarrow f(n) > cg(n))$.  In other words, for every $g$, there is an $f$ such that for any scalar multiple of $g$, no matter how big, $f$ eventually dominates that scalar multiple.  Of course, the larger the scalar multiple, the later you will have to wait (i.e. $B$ will have to be bigger) until $f$ dominates that scalar multiple of $g$.

Comment: $f$ is still difficult to control because $c$ can be arbitrarily large...

Comment: Try a few simple, concrete examples first.  Probably once you have the right intuition for the problem, it becomes trivial.  So try $g(x) \equiv 1$, and then $g(x) = x$.

Comment: Hi, I am back. I think the point is to control n. So set $f(n) = ng(n)$, then let $n = max(\lceil{B}\rceil, c + 1)$. Then $f(n) = f(c+1) = (c+1)g(c+1) > cg(c+1) = cg(n)$. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, that's nearly perfect.  The only issue in your proof is that you can't just say $f(n) = f(c+1)$ because $n$ may not equal $c+1$ since it's the max of $c+1$ and another number.  But $n \geq c+1$, and that's all you really need.

Answer (score 1):

You want a function $f$ that grows much faster than $g$.  Hint: try $f$ of the form $f_1(n) + f_2(g(n))$, where $f_1(n)$ by itself will work if $g(n)$ is bounded, and $f_2(g(n))$ would work if it is unbounded.

Comment: This does not control $c$ though?

Comment: "Grows much faster" means that it works for every $c$.

Comment: I don't think it has to grow much faster, but just larger at one point.

Comment: To take care of the $c$, one point is not enough.